# PHP - submit <a> with method POST?

Tags: php, post, get

I have the following button which is actually an  tag:

`<a id=\"Send_Mail\" class=\"btn btn-block btn-primary btn-xs\" target=\"_blank\" href=\"./sendmail.php?crs=$crs\" method=\"POST\">Send</a>`

1.The problem I have is that when the button/link is clicked, my PHP script cannot verify `if (isset($_POST['Send_Mail'])) {` since the POST method is not supported by  links.

2.I could change it to , but then have the problem that I must submit the $crs variable along with the link which  doesnt allow.

What to do? How can I check whether an  tag has really been clicked?

Thanks

Comment: please paste your code..

Comment: 1.use form instead of link. 2. use ajax but i don't think it will useful in your case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just submit page on click on anchor tag:

```
<a id=\"Send_Mail\" class=\"btn btn-block btn-primary btn-xs\" >Send</a>
```

Jquery:

```
$("#Send_Mail").click(function() {
   $("#form_id").submit();
});
```

Comment: but this would mean that I need to have a <form> tag encapsulating the link, which I dont have. Is there any PHP alternative to checking if a link has been clicked?

Comment: yes you need to to have form tag for submitting form

Answer (score 0):

You can set `session` for `$crs` variable and can access it in another page.In that way you can use post with submit button of `<form>` and you don't have to use link.try it